# Scrapy only crawls the first page when there is more than one start_url in start_requests

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have several spiders running and collecting products from auction websites. All spiders follow more or less the same basic pattern from products list page to product detail page and paginate to the next products list page. I have stored the start_urls for each website in a mysql table which feeds the start_requests for each spider. This works all very well except for one specific website and I can't figure out what's wrong.

When the 'start_requests' of this spider receives only one start_url it crawls each products list page until the final page. When the 'start_requests' receives more than one start_url it will only crawl the first page and then goes on to the next start_url.

At first I thought the problem was not setting the correct headers/cookies, but this didn't seem to solve the issue. What I think the solution would be is that the crawler waits for the first start_url to finish completely and then move on to the next. But I can't figure out how to make this work.

Below is the spider in question, again I've used this spider for other sites without any issues. Note: I replaced the mysql logic with a list which contains the start_urls.

I've solved a many issues by just reading about it on Stackoverflow, but now I am really stuck. Any help or suggestion from the community is greatly appreciated!

```py
import scrapy
import re
import hashlib
from lotbot.items import LotbotItem
from scrapy import Request

class VendunotarisSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "vendurotterdam"
    allowed_domains = ['vendurotterdam.nl']

    def start_requests(self):
        rows = [[1777, 'https://vendurotterdam.nl/catalogus/?auction_id=1229'], [1761, 'https://vendurotterdam.nl/catalogus/?auction_id=1224'], [1731, 'https://vendurotterdam.nl/catalogus/?auction_id=1225']]

        for row in rows:
            yield Request(url=row[1], callback=self.parse_list, cb_kwargs=dict(sale=row[0]))


    def parse_list(self, response, sale):
        lot_page_links = response.css('div.items div#objectinfo div.col-lg-12.col-xs-12 a')
        yield from response.follow_all(lot_page_links, self.parse_lot, cb_kwargs=dict(sale=sale))

        pagination_links = response.xpath("//div/a[contains(text(), 'Volgende')]")
        yield from response.follow_all(pagination_links, self.parse_list, cb_kwargs=dict(sale=sale))


    def parse_lot(self, response, sale):
        def extract_with_css(query):
            return response.css(query).get()

        item = LotbotItem()
        item['source_url'] = response.request.url
        item['catalog_url'] = response.request.url
        item['productId'] = response.xpath('//table/tr[1]/td[3]/b/text()').get()
        item['name'] = extract_with_css('h1.item-detail-title::text')
        if extract_with_css('div.modal-body') is None:
            item['description'] = extract_with_css('span.title::text') + ' ' + response.xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/section/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/text()').getall()[2]
        else:
            item['description'] = extract_with_css('div.modal-body::text') + ' ' + response.css('div.col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.detail-right div ::text').getall()[8]
        relative_img_urls = response.css('div.slider_image div a::attr(href)').get()
        item['image_urls'] = [relative_img_urls]
        item['estimates'] = response.css('div.box-black.pull-right::text').get()
        item['price_result'] = response.xpath('//td[contains(@id,"highest_bid_td")]/text()').get()
        checksum_string = str(sale) + response.request.url
        item['checksum'] = hashlib.md5(checksum_string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        item['sale_id'] = sale

        yield item

    def url_join(self, urls, response):
        joined_urls = []
        for url in urls:
            joined_urls.append(response.urljoin(url))

        return joined_urls
```

Comment: The logic you've implemented is fine. A sample run of the spider on my machine crawls all the links in the `start_urls` and then goes to the following pages. See sample output of the run [here](https://pastebin.com/vAnVvdSH). Also note that the asynchronous nature of scrapy makes the way that scrapy will crawl different pages unpredictable. Therefore you cannot tell exactly when a particular link will be visited or in which order.

Comment: Thank you @msenior_, very kind of you to run the spider on your machine. It appears I must look for the issue somewhere else. Might there be any settings in the settings.py that could cause this behavior, cause I am definitely only getting the first page of each start_url. But I will also create a new virtual environment and have another go at it. Thanks again!

Comment: @msenior_ thanks again for your efforts. After a clean install of Scrapy I ran into the same problem, but after I've changed the 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY' to False I was able to get to page 2,3 and 4 but no further. Each auction contains at least 10 product pages, but I am not getting near. Therefore I am wondering if you were able to get past the first couple of pages, your output shows it goes until page 2.
Could it be that the site is blocking the spider at some point? Which doesn't make sense to me because I am able to crawl all 40+ pages when I feed the start_request with only one start_url.